# Receive file in Android using the intent the file produces when opened

Tags: java, android, android-intent, deserialization

My App can serialize an object and send it via WhatsApp to another phone:

```
FullRecipe fr = new FullRecipe(data);
String extension = ".rec";
String name = "recipe";    
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(sdcard, name + extension);

try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(fr);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("application/rec");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(intent);
```

I use a custom file extension and added intent-filters to my Manifest so my application appears in the application chooser if I try to open the file by clicking on it in WhatsApp.
Now I want to deserialize the clicked file with the following code:

```
FullRecipe fr;
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
String path = data.getPath();
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    fr = (FullRecipe) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
    fis.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I click on the sent file in WhatsApp and select my application, my application starts (it receives the intent), but I get this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /item/86477: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

Obviously '/item/86477' isn't a proper file path, but how can I get the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but how can I get the right one?

You don't, as it is not a file and has no path.

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Then, reconsider your plan. Not everybody updates their app to the latest version, let alone quickly. If you change the structure of `FullRecipe` between versions, now you will have incompatible serializations (old and new), and you will need to somehow reconcile that programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! What would you propose to do in order to share data between app-users?

Comment: @Felix: Well, I'd start by using something other than Java serialization (e.g., JSON, XML). Then, you will need to specifically bake into that serialized data some sort of version number for the serialization format. Then, you will need to have smarts to be able to consume whatever you receive, gracefully failing or something if you get a data structure with a higher version number than the app knows how to handle (e.g., the user has not updated their app in a while).